# Distributivity of the negative sign in additive groups

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

As a fan of Khan academy, I am interested in finding logic behind mathematics but I am unable to get over how does distributing the negative sign in an additive group work
$$Ex : -(5a+2b+3c) = -5a-2b-3c$$
Can someone explain how.

Comment: By distributivity of multiplication $-(u+v)=(-1)(u+v)=(-1)u+(-1)v=-u-v\,$.

Comment: This means that in an additive group the sum of $5a+2b+3c$ and $-5a-2b-3c$ is zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $-(5a+2b+3c)=x $.  By definition $x $ is the number so that $(5a+2b+3c)+x=0$.

lets add $ (5a +2b+3c)+(-5a-2b-3c)=$

$5a +2b + 3c +(-5a)+(-2b)+(-3c)=$

$(5a+(-5a))+(2b+(-2b))+(3c+(-3c))=$

$0+0+0=0$

Therefore  $(-5a-2b-3c) $ is the number $x $ so that $(5a+2b+3c)+x=0$.

So $(-5a-2b-3c)=-(5a+2b+3c) $.

...or...

We could prove $(-1)a= -a $

(as $a+(-1)a=1*a+(-1)a=(1-1)a=0*a=(0+0)a=0*a+0*a $ so $0= 0*a-0*a=0*a+0*a-0*a=0*a=a+(-1)a $.  So $(-1)a = -a$).

So

$(5a+2b+3c)=(-1)(5a+2b+3c)=(-1)5a+(-1)(2b)+(-1)(3c)= -5a-2b-3c $.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication distributes over addition

$-(5a+2b+3c)= (-1)(5a+2b+3c)= (-1)5a+(-1)2b+(-1)3c = -5a-2b-3c$

Comment: So you mean that the "-" is actually a -1

Comment: @KunalMehta in this example yes because we are multiplying.

Comment: In more or less mathematical terms, minus sign has two "avatars"; either as a "unary" operator or as "binary" operator. In other terms, either it needs, for existing, a single "operand", for example with operand $5$, you get $-5$, or it needs two "operands", say 7 and 4, to be usedl for "operation" $7-4$. If the operand are $5$ and $7$, you get $5-7=-2$, and in this relationship, you have the two "avatars" of "minus sign"...

Comment: It does mean $(-1)x=-x $ but it needs to be proved. $-x $ is the number so that $x +(-x)=0$. So you simply need to prove $x+(-1)x=0$. To do that prove, 0x=0 (Because 0 =0x-0x =(0+0)x -0x =0x+0x-0x=0x+(0x-0x)=0x+0=0). Then show x+(-1)x=1x+(-1x)=(1-1)x=0x=0. So x+(-1)x=0 so -x=(-1)x.